# How come parameterized methods can be implicitly bound in some cases and not others?

Tags: java, generics

I came across this issue when refactoring code recently:

The method "getList()" below has a parameterized return type.  Below that, I've put three methods which attempt to implicitly bind `<T>` to `<Integer>`.

What I can't figure out is why the first two compile and run correctly, whereas the third one (bindViaMethodInvocation) won't even compile.

Any clues?

In looking for a similar question on StackOverflow, I came across this question:
[Inferred wildcard generics in return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294227/inferred-wildcard-generics-in-return-type).  The answer there (credit [Laurence Gonsalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90848/laurence-gonsalves)) has a couple of useful reference links to explain what is supposed to be going on:
*"The problem here (as you suggested) is that the compiler is performing [Capture Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190795). I believe this is as a result of [§15.12.2.6 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.6) of the JLS."*

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.*;

public class ParameterizedReturn
{
    // Parameterized method
    public static <T extends Object> List<T> getList()
    {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public static List<Integer> bindViaReturnStatement()
    {
        return getList();
    }

    public static List<Integer> bindViaVariableAssignment()
    {
        List<Integer> intList = getList();
        return intList;
    }

    public static List<Integer> bindViaMethodInvocation()
    {
        // Compile error here
        return echo(getList());
    }

    public static List<Integer> echo(List<Integer> intList)
    {
        return intList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt!  I guess I didn't do the markdown correctly on those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first two methods use `getList()` in a context subject to *assignment conversion* - either an assignment to `List<Integer>` or the return statement from a method returning `List<Integer>`. The same *isn't* true for `bindViaMethodInvocation` - using an expression as a method argument is *not* subject to assignment conversion.

From the [JLS section 15.12.2.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.8):

> If any of the method's type arguments were not inferred from the types of the actual arguments, they are now inferred as follows.
>
> - If the method result occurs in a context where it will be subject to assignment conversion (§5.2) to a type S, then let R be the declared result type of the method, and let R' = R[T1 = B(T1) ... Tn = B(Tn)] where B(Ti) is the type inferred for Ti in the previous section, or Ti if no type was inferred.

The JLS isn't very clear on why return statements count here. The closest I can find is in [14.17](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.17):

> A return statement with an Expression must be contained in a method declaration that is declared to return a value (§8.4) or a compile-time error occurs. The Expression must denote a variable or value of some type T, or a compile-time error occurs. The type T must be assignable (§5.2) to the declared result type of the method, or a compile-time error occurs.

(It would be nice if section 5.2 stated that return statements *were* subject to assignment conversions.)

Answer (score 0):

JLS 3 #15.12.2.8 allows type inference in limited contexts. I grade it as a design mistake. The meaning of an expression should be context free, that would be easier for everybody.

Because the meaning of `getList()` varies depending on its surroundings, which is counter-intuitive to Java programmers(never had that before), you find it puzzling that the first 2 compiles, and the 3rd doesn't. And you are not alone, this type of question has been raised repeatedly. They can tell us to RTFS, but the more one needs to read a spec, the worse the spec is.

Of course, we must be practical if a context dependent interpretation is really useful and needed. However there is little evidence supporting that. This kind of type inference is sinisterly dangerous, and most code using it are 99% wrongly designed. It's unclear what they had in mind that they find it necessary to add this type inference rule.

If Java generics is "reified", i.e. value of `T` is available to method invocation at runtime, we can imagine such type inference be safe and useful. However, `T` is not available at runtime, so `getList()` invocation is context free, it's impossible to return the correct type expected by the call site. Unless there's some extralinguistic app logic that guards the type soundness. Then it's hardly "static typing".

Some people had gone further and requested the following type inference:

```
Object getFoo(){ .. }

Bar bar = getFoo();
```

because "if I wrote that, of course I know the runtime return type is Bar, so stop questioning me, stupid compiler!"

I respect that opinion, but you should choose a difference language. In both static and dynamic typing, the programer knows the types, but the point of static typing is that, we want to manifestly write down the types in source anyway - not to help the compiler, but to benefit ourselves. "Type inference" violated that exact goal; it should only be done if it does not create any myth to anyone reading the code of what the types really are. Unfortunately Java's type inference is very very mythical.