# Is is possible to remove generic type parameters from object constructor in Java?

Tags: java, generics, constructor

In Java it is tiring to have to write:

```
Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair<String, String>("one", "two");
```

It would be nice if the types were inferred for you so you could at least do this:

```
Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair("one", "two");
```

And skip the generic params again.

You can make a static method that can cheat around it like so:

```
public static <T, S> Pair<T, S> new_(T one, S two) {
    return new Pair<T, S>(one, two);
}
```

And then use it like: `Pair.new_("one", "two")`.

Is it possible to build the type inferencing into the constructor so that hack can be avoided?

I was thinking of something like:

```
public <S,T> Pair(S one, T two) {
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
}
```

But then you run into generic type collisions.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: That default behavior was actually proposed for JDK 1.7, but I don't think it got included.

Comment: @Justin, that would have been a nice feature to have.

Comment: Does your IDE not auto-complete that for you?

Comment: @Yaneeve, could you please elaborate on that question?  I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @JustinKSU It was included in the form of [diamond operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)

Comment: @jjnguy, I meant that when I declare a class such as Pair, and then when I wish to write a new statement, my IDE (intellij, currently, but I remember eclipse doing the same) can complete the statement (after writing the new keyword) with Pair<String,String>(), after which I just add "one" then "two"...

Comment: @Yaneeve, good point.  My IDE does auto-complete that.  However, it is also more clutter to read.  Esp. if you have things like `Map<String, List<String>>`.  I guess I'd like it better for readability and maintainability in the future.

Comment: Hmm, where did they hide the language specification? http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/ does not work anymore, as well as the web site feedback link there. :-/

Comment: Incidentally, [beware of failure to infer wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1294227/1968) in this code.

Comment: On a completely off-topic note, is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number/4924618#4924618) really you?

Comment: @Michael, I'm not sure.  I never use `toCharArray` in my code...so I'm not sure why I would suggest that.  I don't remember writing that, or answering a question I already had the top answer on with a completely different answer.  I'm a bit spooked.

Comment: Oh, waffles must have merged the users before you saw it. The user there was called NotJustin and had the same gravatar and a remarkably similar email. The weird thing is that according to your user history, you weren't even going by Justin on February 7.

Comment: Hmmm, odd.  Were there any other answers by that user?

Comment: No, just the one. Doesn't matter now, I guess. Just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It s common to have a helper method which will imply the types for you.

```
Pair<String, String> pair = Pair.of("one", "two");
```

then it doesn't seem like such a hack.

It would also be nice if Java had a built in Pair class. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I noted that in my question.  I was wondering if there was a way around needing that.

Comment: All you can do is hide the ugliness with a nicer name and perhaps a `import static Pair.pairOf;` and use just the method name.

Comment: I think `Pair.of` is a lot cleaner than a static imported `pairOf` method!

Comment: I think "factory method" is the term people generally use for this

Comment: @newacct, It is a factory method, but a helper method is one which helps hide away a piece of ugliness or complexity.  This is the point I wanted to emphasis.

Comment: @Oscar, haha yeah.  I was surprised as well.

Comment: @jjnguy, Perhaps you should have answered your own question. ;) I suggested changing the name so it appears more natural even if technically it is the same solution.

Comment: @OscarRyz, I don't always understand why I get as many or as few votes as I do.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 7 you can use the "diamond" operator:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, Int> map = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, List<String>> lolmap = new HashMap<>();
```

- Here is the JSR which defines it: [JSR334](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=334)
- Example using the Diamond operator and some other Java7 features: [New language features in Java 7](http://code.joejag.com/2009/new-language-features-in-java-7/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the declaration of a variable of a particular type, and the instantiation of an object to be referenced by that variable, are two different operations. Strings are generally hard to mistake, but let's say you were setting up pairs of numbers (maybe X-Y coordinates):

```
Pair<float,float> myCoords = new Pair(3,4);
```

This brings up a quandary; you're declaring a `Pair<float, float>`, but assigning an object that would probably be inferred as `Pair<int,int>`, unless the compiler were given enough intelligence to take the type of the variable being set into account when inferring the instantiated object's generic types (highly unlikely). Java generics, AFAIK, are not covariant, and even if they were, int does not inherit from float. I don't know of a non-duck-typed language that would handle a situation like this correctly.

Comment: Java does not support primitives as type parameters, thus it would at least have to be `Pair<Float, Float>` and `Pair<Integer, Integer>`.

Comment: My apologies; I code in C# mostly, which does allow use of the primitive "aliases" for the actual class names.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's tiring but that way you ensure type safety of your code. This code is a legal Java code (despite of the warning from the compiler):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
    a.add(1);
    ArrayList<String> b = a;
    System.out.println(b.get(0));
  }
}
```

But the compiler cannot infer the type now, yet a is assignment compatible with b. Try running it, and a runtime error would occur.

Comment: Yeah, don't use raw types here.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer things to be explicit. When things are inferred, they can be inferred incorrectly, or the method can be used incorrectly without any notice because the system infers how to handle the incorrect arguments.