# Cannot infer type of Class<?>

Tags: java, generics

I have a static utility method named `toSet()` which receives objects and returns a `Set`.

```
public static <T> Set<T> toSet(T item, T... otherItems) {
    Set<T> items = new HashSet<T>();
    items.add(item);
    items.addAll(Arrays.asList(otherItems));
    return items;
}
```

The method works fine with other object but will yield compilation when I want to make a `Set` of `Class<?>`.

```
Set<String> strings = toSet("OK", "This works well", "No problem");
Set<Integer> numbers = toSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

but

```
    Class<?> test = String.class;
    Set<Class<?>> entities = toSet(test);
```

will yield `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Class<capture#5-of ?>> to Set<Class<?>>`.

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I achieve this without casting?

Comment: Found a more detailed post: possible duplicate of [Inferred wildcard generics in return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294227/inferred-wildcard-generics-in-return-type)

Comment: @PaulBellora: thanks a lot for the link. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like type inference breaks down in this case, for reasons someone else can hopefully explain. Casting isn't necessary - just specify the type parameter explicitly:

```
Set<Class<?>> entities = MyClass.<Class<?>>toSet(test);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Another way to workaround this is to use the answer of the question that PaulBellora linked above. To sum up, in this case, I have to explicitly declare the type for the compiler know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way also :

```
 Class<String> test = String.class;
 Set<Class<String>> entities = toSet(test);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But here I want to make a `Set` of `Class<?>` (every instances of `Class`, not just `Class<String>`).